# question about URLs

Tags: url, salesforce

is it possible to have a url that has a param with an & embedded in the value (eg &FirmName=Test&Firm) and not have the browser treat that & in the value as the beginning of another param???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to urlencode it - `&` is `%26`:

```
&FirmName=Test%26Firm
```

Comment: i already tried that....i am urlencoding the string...for some reason the browser doesnt recognize that i did that and doesnt populate the form...

Comment: Are you sure the server side code is actually using the query string input in this manner?

Comment: The browser won't automatically populate a form based on the querystring - you need to do that serverside and print out value="..." for each input.

Comment: problem is that the server side code that generates the jsp page is out of my control...is there a way i can fool the browser...there is no way for me to get to the server side code....
heres what happens....i assemble the url on my side...after url encoding it i send it over to a jsp page that is basically hosted by salesforce that generates an intermediate form on the server and then when i move from the intermediate form to the form where the data is to be displayed that form is empty because of the above problem...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just encode the "&" using [URL encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp) ("%26")

Most web programming frameworks have functions that take a string and URL-encode it